# How a Boolean method should not return for case sensitive c#

Tags: c#, boolean, case-sensitive

I have a Boolean function which checks the names from database, If any name exists in database which returns true. my function is

```
  public bool rawMtrlExists(string strRawMtrl)
    { 
        var rwMtrl = prodctsDC.productsnrwmtrls.Where(c => c.item_Ctgry == 'R' || c.item_Ctgry == 'B'||c.item_Ctgry=='G').Distinct().ToArray();
        return rwMtrl.Count(d => d.item_Name == strRwMtrl) > 0;
    }
```

My problem is.. If my strRawMtrl orgument having the same word but with casesensitive, the method returning false. I mean name in database field is **Central Processing Unit**. Iam passing  as **central processing unit**. In this case It is returning false but I need true. Please anybody help me to return not for case sensitive words too.

Comment: Is there any specific technical reason to have such horrible member and method names? what in the world is `prdTcDC.productsnrwmtrls`?!?!?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use overloaded `Equals` method with `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`:

```
d.item_Name.Equals(strRwMtrl, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

Another *hacky* way which I don't prefer since it creates two more strings in heap:

```
d.item_Name.ToLower() == strRwMtrl.ToLower()
```

Comment: While the first method is certainly better than the second, it is better to use `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973919.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this. Using `ToArray()` forces next parts of query to run locally. Also `Disticnt()` redundant.

```
public bool rwMtrlExists(string strRwMtrl)
{ 
    return prdTcnDC
             .productsnrwmtrls
             .Where(c => c.item_Ctgry == 'R'
                      || c.item_Ctgry == 'B'
                      || c.item_Ctgry == 'G')
            .Any(d => d.item_Name.ToLower() == strRwMtrl.ToLower());
}
```